# When using a custom ActionBar custom view, the icon background is in the original color

Tags: android, background, icons, android-actionbar

While working on my application, I used a custom ActionBar view:

```
this.getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_bg);
this.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
```

Ubfortunately, as you can see, the whole ActionBar is not customized and the icons have the default actionbar background.

Is there a way to fix that?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My current workaround:

```
<resources>
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">ANY_HEX_COLOR_CODE</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try use the backgroundStacked:

```
 <item name="backgroundStacked">#YourColor</item>
```